# HTML parse order / script execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following lines are from the official jQuery website

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

I'm not sure about the HTML parse order, or should I say script execution order.

The question is: Will line 2 wait for line 1 to load? I doubt it.

If line 1 is still being loaded (say it's 3000KB, and takes long), and line 2 is executed already. window.jQuery would always be false, and so the second js is always included. If that's true, what is line 1 for anyway?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scripts are executed in the order they are in the document. The browser waits for the script to load before executing the scripts following it.

If this weren't the case, you couldn't have any two files be dependent of each other. You'd have to put everything in the same file because otherwise the script execution order would be practically random.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will wait with parsing any html until the script is loaded and parsed. This is one reason why you should load externa scripts at the end of your page so script will not blocking the html rendering.

Comment: ok, regarding where to put the scripts, top or bottom: <script>...</script><div></div>, will the parser wait for the script to be loaded to parse the div? YSlow suggests to put scripts at bottom, but I see all those BIG websites they don't follow this rule. so when or what kind of scripts should I put at bottom?

Comment: Yes first the script will be loaded and executed then the div will be parsed. All scripts that you dont need to display your side correctly should be loaded at the end of your side.

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk about the more traditional way of handling without using attribute `defer` or `async`

The browsers will:

1. Download `script`s, blocking other resource from downloading
2. Parse the scripts
3. Execute the scripts

See Ch1, Loading and Executing from [High Performance JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802806.do)

Here's another good reference 12.3. Execution of JavaScript Programs from  [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)