# ValidatorEnable is not defined

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to enable and disable a required field validator using javascript but keep getting the error message ValidatorEnable is not defined. PLease find code below, any help would be great.

*ASP.Net*

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="True"  Display="None" ID="rfvMostRecentEmployer" ControlToValidate="txtMostRecentEmployer" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Most recent employer title is a required field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

*Javascript*

```
var validatorMostRecentEmployer = document.getElementById('<%= rfvMostRecentEmployer.ClientID %>');

ValidatorEnable(validatorMostRecentEmployer, !hasCv);
```

*Code Behind*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rblCV.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("ShowCvOptions();"));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that function `ValidatorEnable`  is placed before calling from any other place.

Comment: In the View source of the page please make sure that the function ValidatorEnable is placed before calling from any other place please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052310/html-parse-order-script-execution-order

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you are trying to run the JavaScript code before the asp.net validator code has been included.

If you are using jQuery then try wrapping the code in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var validatorMostRecentEmployer = document.getElementById('<% =rfvMostRecentEmployer.ClientID %>');

  ValidatorEnable(validatorMostRecentEmployer, !hasCv);
});
```

(I also incorporated Ashwin's advice which is the correct way to reference asp.net controls from JavaScript)

Comment: The javascript is run on click and I don't click until the page is fully loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be that you have another JavaScript error on the page which is preventing the ValidatorEnable function being included. Have you checked for errors with a JavaScript debug tool such as the Error Console in firefox? (Press CTRL-SHIFT-J to open)

Comment: Good thinking but there is no javascript errors  in Chrome console, this is really frying my head as the code I have should work. Thanks for chipping in, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

ClientID could be the problem.

```
var validatorMostRecentEmployer = document.getElementById('<% =rfvMostRecentEmployer.ClientID %>');

ValidatorEnable(validatorMostRecentEmployer, !hasCv);
```

**UPDATE** Not an elegant solution though but it works, if nothing does.

```
function disableValidator() 
{ 
var myval = document.getElememtById('<% =rfvMostRecentEmployer.ClientID %>'); 
myval.style.cssText=""; 
myval.style.display='none'; 
myval.style.accelerator=true; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry that is how I am inserting the client ID, I will update the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the server side code I found the following code that was disabling the client side script and must have been stopping it getting registered:

```
//Clear client side validators
foreach (BaseValidator bv in Page.Validators)
{
    bv.EnableClientScript = false;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped out with this.