# Does javascript load serially on every browser?

Tags: javascript, serial-processing

if i have multiple javascript file on a page, will it always load serially across browser?

```
<script src='test1.js'></script>
<script src='test2.js'></script>
<script src='test3.js'></script>
```

for example, if the test*.js would write 1,2 and 3 using console.log, would it always write 1,2,3 on every browser?

if it isn't, is there a way to make it synchronous/serially?

Comment: i believe yes, although I can't point you to any source. But it wouldn't make sense if it won't be loaded serially, because what if test2.js had code that depended on test1.js. it would error if doesn't load in order.

Comment: You can have a look at http://headjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML parse order / script execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052310/html-parse-order-script-execution-order)

Comment: They will probably not load in serial order, but will be executed in order

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does inline javascript block the UI thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545653/does-inline-javascript-block-the-ui-thread)

Comment: Well, the above refers to UI thread, but it is obvious that any non-deferred non-async script will block rendering of the main thread including the execution of other scripts.

Comment: @Kiswono Prayogo: Normally recent browsers make 5 to 6 parallel requests at a time. So your download will be parallel but the execution order will always be serial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually tested your example in the following browsers, each loaded serially:

- Firefox
- IE 7-9
- Chrome
- Opera
- Safari

[Please read this exhaustive answer for more information on why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8996894/944301)

Answer (score 1):

> for example, if the test*.js would write 1,2 and 3 using console.log, would it always write 1,2,3 on every browser?

Yes it would.

Browsers may load scripts in parallel, but will always execute them in order. An exception is when you have an `async` or `defer` attribute set on the `script` tag. Scripts dynamically created (through JS) are also async in nature.

Beware that placing too many scripts in your page may slow down rendering. If the server takes too long to serve one of the files as the markup below the `script` won't be rendered until the script has loaded and executed. It is good practice to minify all your JS files into a single one for production environment and use more script tags with good reason (e.g. using a CDN-hosted library).